# Output in only one line but

Tags: shell, shell-script

I execute the script and I want this output

```
SENTENCIA : select 1 from dual;
LA CONEXION ES : usu/clave@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=bd)))
```

Code

```
declare -a arr=("usu<>clave<>host<>1525<>bd")
D="<>"  #Delimitador
# Indica el separador (en este caso ninguno) si no se pone la variable sentencia la parte en trozos
IFS=

export sentencia="select 1 from dual;"

for maquina in "${arr[@]}";  
do 

# Separa los campos en variables
sList=($(echo $maquina | sed -e 's/'"$D"'/\n/g' | while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/[\t ]/'"$D"'/g'; done))
for (( i = 0; i < ${#sList[@]}; i++ )); do
  sList[i]=$(echo ${sList[i]} | sed 's/'"$D"'/ /')
done

printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" $sentencia;

# Sustituye los valores dentro de la cadena de conexión
cadena_conexion=`echo "${sList[0]}/${sList[1]}@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${sList[2]})(PORT=${sList[3]}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${sList[4]})))"`
printf "LA CONEXION ES : %s \n" $cadena_conexion;

done
```

but I obtain this output when I use FS= or not.

```
-- WITH FS=

$ sh ejecutar_sqlplus_remoto.sh
SENTENCIA : select 1 from dual;
LA CONEXION ES : usu
clave
host
1525
bd/@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)))

-- WITHOUT FS=

$ sh ejecutar_sqlplus_remoto.sh
SENTENCIA : select
SENTENCIA : 1
SENTENCIA : from
SENTENCIA : dual;
LA CONEXION ES : usu/clave@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=bd)))
```

Mi problem is that I use "FS=" then when I display the value of sentencia it appears in 1 line but cadena_conexion is displayed in four lines. If I comment the "FS=" line I get the opposite, the value of sentencia in four lines and the value of cadena_conexion in one line. I want to display both variables in only one line. I don't want to cut neither of the variables in lines. I hope this time I have explained well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" "$sentencia"
```

with quotes.

When use without quotes

```
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" $sentencia;
```

is replaced by (I leave out `;` )

```
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" select 1 from dual
```

as there is only one print pattern (e.g. %s) printf is called multiple time.

```
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" select 
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" 1 
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" from 
printf "SENTENCIA : %s \n" dual
```